# mozilla firefox extension: creating a javascript library and using it in a HTML page

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I created a library in a firefox extension :

```
./components/main.js
./skin/icon.png
./install.rdf
./chrome.manifest
```

my **main.js** would use define a class calling a mozilla TCPScoket ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TCPSocket)

```
function MYLib() {}    
MYLib.prototype.doWork = function(arg1,arg2) { /* do something with TCPScoket */}
```

How should I use my library on the client side in the HTML ?

I'm looking for something like (?):

```
<html><head><script>
var mylib = MozillaApiThing.createNewInstance("chrome://myextension/", "MYLib");
 ....
 </script>(...)
```

Comment: You could try search on Google: "firefox extension github" since Github is full of open source, you might find something useful

Comment: I tried that : I cannot find anything specific on github/MDN . Furthermore a large part on MDN seems outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chrome` or `resource` (not in restartless) URLs are available as direct URLs (ie you can enter them into address-bar and they show up). Therefore you can use it as a simple script src

```
<script src="chrome://myextension/components/jsfile.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, you can read the JS file (ie with XMLHttpRequest or FileUtils.jsm or osfile.jsm) and then insert the content into the page with `createElement('script')`, `textContent` and `appendChild()`

Alternatively, you can try [The message manager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox/The_message_manager)

**Note:** Inserted local script into the page will have the content page scope (no access to browser scope API)

Comment: not tested yet, but can  use the Mozilla API (like TCPScoket ) without asking for the user's permission ?